# Using the Ruby pg gem, what is the best way to add potentially null values to a database?

Tags: ruby, postgresql, pg

I am trying to add an object to the database like this:

```
DB.exec("INSERT INTO patients (name, birthdate) VALUES ('#{name}', '#{birthdate}');")
```

The problem is that if either of these values is nil, the data will be saved incorrectly or there will be a syntax error.

I can use if statements to send a different SQL statement depending on whether or not each value is nil, but this seems ugly and I'm wondering how to do this better.

Comment: What do you want to do if one or both values is `NULL`? Run the insert with placeholder values? Run a different statement entirely? No-op?

Answer (score 0):

Use [`prepare`](http://rubydoc.info/github/ged/ruby-pg/PGconn:prepare) to build a prepared statement with placeholders:

```
DB.prepare('new_patient', 'insert into patients (name, birthdate) values ($1, $2)')
```

Note that this uses numbered parameters so

> ... bind parameters are represented as $1, $1, $2, etc., inside the SQL query.

rather than the positional `?` parameters that you might be used to.

Then use [`exec_prepared`](http://rubydoc.info/github/ged/ruby-pg/PGconn:exec_prepared) execute the prepared statement and supply the parameter values then:

```
DB.exec_prepared('new_patient', [ name, birthdate ])
```

The interface to `exec_prepared` is a bit odd as it wants the parameters in an explicit array.

Now, if `name.nil?` then you'll get a NULL in the `name` column and if `birthdate.nil?` you'll get a NULL in the `birthdate` column.

If you ever find yourself writing `#{...}` inside an SQL statement, think again, there is almost always a better and safer way.